# Calculate the probability that the selected patient’s cancer is stage 1

Tags: probability

In a certain group of cancer patients, each patient’s cancer is classified in
exactly one of the following five stages: stage 0, stage 1, stage 2, stage 3, or
stage 4.

i) 75% of the patients in the group have stage 2 or lower.

ii) 80% of the patients in the group have stage 1 or higher.

iii) 80% of the patients in the group have stage 0, 1, 3, or 4.

One patient from the group is randomly selected. Calculate the probability
that the selected patient’s cancer is stage 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the third fact, you get that
$$P(\text{patient has stage 2 cancer}) = 1-P(\text{patient has stage 0, 1, 3 or 4 cancer}) = 1 - 0.8 = 0.2.$$

From the first piece of information, you get

\begin{align*}
&P(\text{patient has stage 0 or 1 cancer})\\ &= P(\text{patient has stage 0, 1 or 2 cancer}) - P(\text{patient has stage 2 cancer})\\
&= 0.75 - 0.2\\
&= 0.55.
\end{align*}
From the second piece of information, you get

\begin{align*}
&P(\text{patient has stage 1, 3 or 4 cancer})\\ &= P(\text{patient has stage 1, 2, 3 or 4 cancer}) - P(\text{patient has stage 2 cancer})\\
&= 0.8 - 0.2\\
&= 0.6.
\end{align*}

From the third fact, you then get
\begin{align*}
&P(\text{patient has stage 0 cancer})\\
&= P(\text{patient has stage 0, 1, 3 or 4 cancer}) - P(\text{patient has stage 1, 3 or 4 cancer})\\
&= 0.8 - 0.6\\
&= 0.2.
\end{align*}
Now we can combine our observations to obtain
\begin{align*}
&P(\text{patient has stage 1 cancer})\\
&= P(\text{patient has stage 0 or 1 cancer}) - P(\text{patient has stage 0 cancer})\\
&= 0.55 - 0.2\\
&= 0.35.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be the events that the patient is stage $0,1,2,3,4$ respectively. Then, you have the relations:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(A\cup B \cup C \cup D \cup E) = 1 \\
&\mathbb{P}(A\cup B \cup C) = 0.75\\
&\mathbb{P}(B \cup C \cup D \cup E) = 0.8\\
&\mathbb{P}(A \cup B \cup D \cup E) = 0.8
\end{align*}
Also, $A,B,C,D,E$ are disjoint. Can you compute $P(B)$?